# C++ keys-value container with variable keys count

Tags: c++, boost, containers

Is there some well known container (in boost for example) which provides access to the same value using different keys of the same type. All keys are unique. Each value may have variable keys count.

Here is very naive implementation:

```
class multi_key_map
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string> flatMap;

public:
    multi_key_map(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::vector<std::string>, std::string>> map)
    {
        for (auto& kvp : map)
        {
            for (auto&& key : kvp.first)
            {
                flatMap.emplace(std::move(key), kvp.second);
            }
        }
    }

    const std::string& operator[](std::string& key) const
    {
      return flatMap.at(key);
    }
};

const multi_key_map vals =
{ 
    { { "k1", "k2", "k3" }, "val1" },
    { { "k4", "k5" }, "val2" },
    { { "k6" }, "val3" }
};

assert(vals["k1"] == "val1");
assert(vals["k2"] == "val1");
assert(vals["k4"] == "val2");
```

But I don't want to reinvent the wheel. I looked at [boost.multiindex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/libs/multi_index/doc/index.html) but I cannot find the desirable simple solution with variable keys count. And it seems that boost.multiindex was developed for purposes other than mine.

Comment: Why can't you do reverse ? Attach _"val"s_ to vector of _"k"s_ ?

Comment: What about using a `std::tuple` or `std::set` as the key?

Comment: @P0W, rigth now it is implemented in production code exactly like you suggest. But is is a bit dirty. We need unnecessary for-loops for example etc.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ, I need access values by each key separately, not by pack of the keys

Comment: Why not have two lookups? key -> packofkeyshash -> value? So your operator[] would do `return valuemap[packofkeys[key]];`

Comment: What do you think is wrong with your current implementation? It looks pretty efficient for reading to me. Is it the duplicate storage of values you want to avoid?

Comment: @themagicalyang, You're rigth, this is the option. But we have ~200 keys (we are writing cmd tool and we need parse cmd text arguments into some structures) and it is a bit inconvenient solution as we should support two heavy maps instead of one.

Comment: @Chris Drew, yes, but maybe I've missed something and there are already implemented standart solution for this task

Comment: You can have a abstract class with a virtual function to return unique key for data of same type  _"std::unordered_map< AbstractKey*, std::string > flatMap;"_ ?

Answer (score 4):

If the values are simple, or small types, inserting the same value for all of its keys, into a `std::map` or a `std::multimap` should work just fine.

For more complicated objects, or if there's some specific need for multiple keys to refer to the same distinct object, use a `std::map` or a `std::multimap` with `std::shared_ptr<value_class>` values, inserting the same `std::shared_ptr` for all of the object value's keys. In this manner, all of the keys will end up referencing the same instance of the object.

Comment: I'd advise against shared_ptr for this. Shared pointer is about shared ownership. Not just about passing references. +1 for the answer

Comment: @sehe: don't keys share ownership here? do you recommend to use raw pointers in this case?